# trying to execute sql command

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

```
CREATE TABLE dw.D_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS
(
   DAYLIGHT_YEAR       INTEGER NOT NULL,
   DAYLIGHT_START      DATE,
   DAYLIGHT_END        DATE,
   Last_Udpated_date   DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
   Last_updated_user   VARCHAR2 (25) DEFAULT 'DW'
);
```

table got created but when i try to run in TOAD AND  insert values in it error pops as command not properly ended. the query for insert is as follows

```
insert into dw.D_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS values 
(2013,'March 10','November 3'),
(2014,'March 9','November 2'),
(2015,'March 8','November 1'),
(2016,'March 13','November 6'),
(2017,'March 12','November 5');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a separate `INSERT INTO` statement for each row and add the `DEFAULT` for each column that you did not specify:

```
insert into dw.D_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS values (2013,'March 10','November 3', DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
insert into dw.D_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS values (2014,'March 9','November 2', DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
insert into dw.D_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS values (2015,'March 8','November 1', DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
insert into dw.D_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS values (2016,'March 13','November 6', DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
insert into dw.D_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS values (2017,'March 12','November 5', DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

Or provide the list of columns into which the columns should be inserted:

```
insert into dw.D_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS (DAYLIGHT_YEAR, DAYLIGHT_START, DAYLIGHT_END) values (2013,'March 10','November 3');
insert into dw.D_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS (DAYLIGHT_YEAR, DAYLIGHT_START, DAYLIGHT_END) values (2014,'March 9','November 2');
insert into dw.D_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS (DAYLIGHT_YEAR, DAYLIGHT_START, DAYLIGHT_END) values (2015,'March 8','November 1');
insert into dw.D_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS (DAYLIGHT_YEAR, DAYLIGHT_START, DAYLIGHT_END) values (2016,'March 13','November 6');
insert into dw.D_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS (DAYLIGHT_YEAR, DAYLIGHT_START, DAYLIGHT_END) values (2017,'March 12','November 5');
```